# Remove map layer when animation restarts Mapbox gl

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am having issues in 'clearing' the map from lines when the user clicks on an element. The idea is to switch between different city-animations on click. For each city, a new geojson is called. The method below using setInterval() generally works but connects the lines from a previous animation with the new one (see image). How can I get rid of this behavior?

```
var geojson = {
    //empty geojson-linestring to append values
};

var counter=0;
var city = 'london';
var citchange = false;

map.on("load", function() {

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'line-animation',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': geojson
        }
    });


  var animation = setInterval(function(){
        animate(city);
    }, 100); //draw 1 new line every 1 sec

  $(document).on('click', '#myCheck li a', function () { //change geojson-data if button is clicked
        //change datainput
        city = $(this).closest('li').attr('value');
        citychange = true;
        clearInterval(animation);
        setTimeout(function() { //restart animation after 1 sec
            setInterval(function(){
                animate(city);
            }, 100);
          }, 100);
    });


  function animate(clicked) {
        $.getJSON(clicked + '.geojson', function(results){
        //if data is finished drawing or if city is changed reset var geojson
        if (counter >= results.features.length-1 || citychange == true) {
              counter = 0;
            geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates = []; //empty out array
            geojson.features[0].geometry.properties = []; //empty out array
              citychange = false;
            }

        var x = results.features[counter].geometry.coordinates[0];
        var y = results.features[counter].geometry.coordinates[1];
        geojson.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push([x, y]); //attach coordinates to geo-json linestring

        map.getSource('line-animation').setData(geojson);  //draw coordinates
        counter++;
        });
    }
});
```

[image]